# redirect get URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm almost done writing the .htaccess file to redirect some URLs to a new domain.

One final thing: I have URLs with this structure:

```
http://www.domain.be/?s=searchterm
```

How do I capture them?

```
RewriteRule ^\?s=(.*)$       http://newsubdomain.domain.be/?s=$1    [NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` only matches the path, not the query string. You need to add a `RewriteCond` for that.

Note the percent back-reference `%1` which inserts the search term captured in the `RewriteCond`. The slash in the `RewriteRule` is in effect a no-op, since we don't care about anything in the URL path.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule / http://newsubdomain.domain.be?s=%1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start your regex with a `/` - so in your case:-

```
RewriteRule ^/\?s=(.*)$
```

Comment: No. As h0ward already mentioned in his answer, the pattern in `RewriteRule` does not match the query string. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule in the box "What is matched?"